# How to make RecyclerView fix header when scrolling

Tags: android, xml

I have a `RecyclerView` that has been filled with data. It's just that when I scroll, the header does not fix the toolbar into position and results go up.

How do I hide the toolbar header when scrolling? Or more easily create fixed scroll on RecyclerView when scrolling?

All my code runs well, it's just a problem with the header that goes up when the scroll

ActivityMain Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.bertho.gmyl.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/whiteColor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

RecyclerView Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvArticle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Result :
[image: Before Scroll]

[image: After Scroll]

Comment: Have you tried to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` as it takes entire screen (including status bar) to draw activity.

For more [info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows).

Comment: If I use `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` my status bar disappear

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: Default, `AppTheme`